# Want to set boxShadow and borderRadius make it default and add it to Material UI theme in a material-UI react project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24); to be applied to every border used in my website. I tried overriding the theme in Material UI , but I am not sure how to modify the boxShadow in the theme and make it default so that I do not have to apply it for every single element in the website

Comment: Have you looked at this part of the documentation? https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/
You can set borderRadius by using shape.borderRadius = 4, and I think you could set box-shadow by setting shadows = ["0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24)"]

Comment: I tried this , but after doing this, should I set every individual className to have borderRadius = theme.borderRadius?

Comment: According to what I see in the documentation, it should get applied automatically unless you set the borderRadius or boxShadow manually somewhere in the application